# How to link my cocoapod with library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

My cocoapod library need to be linked with some lib, let's say "libFoo.a". How can i add headers to search path (`Libs/foo/include`) and library path to link (`Libs/foo/lib`)?

I've used:

```
s.ios.library = "Foo"
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(PODS_ROOT)/Libs/foo/include" }
```

but when `lint`ing i'm getting an error:

> ld: library not found for -lFoo

Let's say here is my cocoapod structure:

```
L---Classes
|   L---myClass.m
|   L---... (other files)
L---Libs
    L---foo
        L---include
        |   L---libFoo.h
        L---lib
            L---libFoo.a
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Would be great to know how, as the problem is real!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to ensure the folder structure is retained, check out [preserve_paths](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#preserve_paths) and also look at podspecs from other pods to see what they do.